# Django - OpenCV: How to serve videos when processing is needed?

Tags: python, django, opencv, video, django-rest-framework

I am working on a web project which aims at enabling users to upload videos, train machine learning algorithms to detect and track some objects in the videos, retrieve (stream or download) the videos including tracking boxes.

My computer vision program is based on OpenCV 3.1 with Python 3.5. For a given video, many operations (Gradients, Gaussian Pyramids…) imply to capture frames from the video and send them to the user as pictures or videos.

I would like to find an efficient way to host the videos.

Currently, I am developing a React/Redux front-end and use Django Rest Framework for the back-end. I was thinking about using a Media Hosting Service to serve the videos to the front-end users and to the Django server when OpenCV processing is needed .

A use case exemple - tracking a Region of Interest on a video :

1. The user uploads his video to the Media Hosting Server,
2. The Django Server downloads the video,
3. My OpenCV app extracts a specific frame,
4. The frame is passed to the front-end via the REST API,
5. The user selects the Region of Interest to track,
6. The ROI is passed to the back-end through the API,
7. My OpenCV app processes each frame to track the ROI …
8. … and renders the video…
9. … with is uploaded to the Media Hosting Server,
10. The user can stream his video with tracking from the Media Hosting Server.

￼[Follow this link to see corresponding flow graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sIRJ.png)

The typical video would be 5-20 Mb. There would be at most tens of users viewing this project but I would like to find a solution that scales well.

I am very new to file serving issues so I would like to get some input from people who know it well and avoid building on shaky ground.

I look forward to hearing from you about the viability of the solution I came with and about better alternatives.

What is the best way to serve videos when some processing is needed on server side ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your solution seems fine. Except, I would suggest (if you haven't already considered, as, it is not mentioned in the question) doing the steps 7,8,9 using some background asynchronous tasks management system (as it seems to be a time as well as resources taking operation) and notify the user when the video is processed, so, he may download/stream it. It would be best for scaling when the time comes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Muhammad. I indeed will have to look at asynchronous tasks management for CV tasks.

Comment: @vwrobel Hi! I just passing by, searching for info. I'm currently trying to accomplish similar project. I know this is outdated, but could you please share what you decide about serving videos? My plan now is to creating a generator with VideoCapture and send frame by frame on canvas through ajax, this is probably horrible solution but i will try different approaches if i'm succeed in some way i will post an answer here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Anatoly ! My current setup is à Graphene/Django backend and a React front end with Apollo client. I get my frames with GraphQL queries. Unfortunately, I have not tested this set up in production with video hosting but everything works fine on local dev :)

Comment: Hi, Did you solve it? can you share the solution?